# Why does explicitly referencing a hierarchy remove the error for "different dimensionality"

Tags: syntax, mdx, hierarchy

I get the SSAS error "Two sets specified in the function have different dimensionality".

I'm actually using same dimensions, the same hierarchy (implicitly), in one set I'm using the "All" member in the other set I'm using leaf members. If I change the member identifiers to explicitly reference the (single) hierarchy then the error goes away.

Why is that?

Here's an example of how I'm getting the error:

```
{Crossjoin( [Measures].[Measure1], [Event].[Category1] ),
Crossjoin( [Measures].[Measure2], [Event].[All] )}
```

And here's basically how I get rid of it (adding explicit hierarchy ref):

```
{Crossjoin( [Measures].[Measure1], [Event].[ByCategory].[Category1] ),
Crossjoin( [Measures].[Measure2], [Event].[ByCategory].[All] )}
```

Any correction explanation would help me to better understand the mdx syntax overall.

In advance, thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a specialist of SSAS but to be sure the both members belongs to the same hierarchy you can try the following:

```
with
  member x as [Event].[Category1].dimension.name
  member y as [Event].[All].dimension.name
select { x , y } on 0 from [your-cube]
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. the query returns (x, y), (ByCategory, ByCategory). Doesn't seem to raise any flag.

Answer (score 1):

Can you pls show the rest of your query?

I have tried to do something similar but it works fine..

```
select {crossjoin( [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
[Product].[Bikes]),
crossjoin([Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount],
[Product].[All])} on columns
from cube
```

[image: result]

Comment: sorry. I deleted and rebuilt my cube from a revised project. It seems to work now, but for some reason not then. This answer adds something, but I don't have the original cube anymore in order to reproduce the error in response to your question.